# How to share Shiny App in Databricks without users requiring credentials?

Tags: r, shiny, azure-databricks

I am currently developing a POC R Shiny app in Azure Databricks. The aim is to be able to showcase this at some stage to others for feedback, etc.

I have done some reading at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/sparkr/shiny to understand what is possible. I can see that "The Shiny app URL generated when you start an app is shareable with other users. Any Azure Databricks user with Can Attach To permission on the cluster can view and interact with the app as long as both the app and the cluster are running."

However, I wanted to know if there was an approach that did not require the people I want to test this with to require Databricks credentials.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.